# Validate input field and block characters

Tags: javascript, validation

Hello guys i have an input field and i want to validate in real time the insterted characters.
I want that this input field accept only letters, number and one blank space. If is inserted for example *, script delete this characters.

Regards

On input filed:

```
onkeyup="check(this,'onlyletter')" onblur="check(this,'onlyletter')
```

On JS:

```
var r={
'onlyletter': // i need correct regular expression
}

function check(o,w){
// i need function
}
```

I have: Abc123'  123* but i accept Abc123 123

Comment: Okay. What's your question? What have you done so far? Where are you running into trouble?

Comment: i have onkeyup and onblur inserted in a input field but i do not make the correct funcion with correct regular expression.

Comment: @ user: Quote the code, show what's not working, give sample inputs and expected outputs vs. what you actually get, etc., etc.

Comment: You could use HTML5 form validation.

Comment: I have not family with html5 form validation :(

Answer (score 0):

### with raw JS:

the clue is in the method transform

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>    
        function transform(elem) {
            var v = elem.value;
            var n = "";

            //loop it to cut of more than 1 -- e.g. on copy & paste
            if(v.length) {
                n = v.slice(-1);
                if( !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n) ) {
                    elem.value = v.substring(0, v.length - 1);
                }
            }
       }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input
        type="text"
        name="date"
        placeholder="Text only!"
        onkeyup="transform(this);"
        maxlength="10"
    >
</body>
</html>
```

### alternate way using jquery

MASK the textfield to only accept letters. now that can be done a number of ways. one is the query mask plugin

you only need query, query-mask and then it is 1 line of code ;)

demo:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){ 
          //masked input for alphabets only 
          //constrained to 20 characters in length without spaces                      
          $("#myTextField").mask("SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS");
      });
</script>
<body>
  <br><input type = "text" id="myTextField" name="Text Field"></br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: edit to add a sec on way using pure javascript, which suits the question

Comment: for checking just text a regex seems overkill